# *SOLVED* Use json data stored in class in future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have a class AdsList which I want to use in future builder.
I know I could have used a for loop and just stored the nested json in a list and use that in future builder, but I'm trying to use a class.
in the fetchJson() method the variable parsed contains the json data and is not Null.
I also commented out snapshot.length since I don't know how to return the length of the class AdsList.

I didn't paste entire file but the widget that doesn't build.

The nested json in the parsed variable has the format like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 1000000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000000
  }
]
```

I'm a bit unsure what fetchJson() is supposed to return,  or  is not valid.

```
Future fetchJson() async {
```

Here is an image when the app is built.
[image: image of the list errors]

It fails with this exception:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
flutter: Class 'AdsList' has no instance method '[]'.
flutter: Receiver: Instance of 'AdsList'
flutter: Tried calling: [](0)
```

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async' 
    show Future;

Future<dynamic> fetchJson() async {
  String url = "http://<hidden_nested_json>";
  final response = await http.get(url);
  var parsed = json.decode(response.body);

  AdsList ads = new AdsList.fromJson(parsed);
  print(ads);
  return ads;
}

class Ad {
  final int id;
  final int sqf;
  final int price;
  final String url;
  //final String thumbnailUrl;

  Ad({
    this.id, 
    this.sqf, 
    this.price, 
    this.url
  }) ;//, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Ad.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Ad(
      finnkode: json['id'] as int,
      areal: json['sqf'] as int,
      prisantydning: json['price'] as int,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      //thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class AdsList {
  final List<Ad> ads;

  AdsList({
    this.ads,
  });


  factory AdsList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<Ad> ads = new List<Ad>();

    ads = parsedJson.map((i)=>Ad.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new AdsList(
      ads: ads,
    );
  }
}

class Houses extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchJson(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
            //itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: snapshot.data[index].id,
                subtitle: snapshot.data[index].price,
            );
            }
          );
        }
      },
      ),
        ) 

      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serialization is wrong! As you're passing the decoded .json which is a Map to your `AdList.fromJson` constructor it must receive a `Map<String,dynamic>` instance and not a `List<dynamic>`.

I add a single key `adList` in .json file just to be more clear.

```
"adList": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 1000000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000000
  }
]
```

In your `AdList` constructor you should have:

```
factory AdsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // here we've a json map with a list "adList" of maps
    // which holds your ads data.
    var listOfMaps = List<Map<String,dynamic>>.from(json['adList']);

    List<Ad> ads = new List<Ad>();
    ads = listOfMaps.map(( adMap )=>Ad.fromJson( adMap )).toList();

    return new AdsList(
      ads: ads,
    );
  }
```

Now you don't need to change your `fetch` method:

```
Future<dynamic> fetchJson() async {
  String url = "http://<hidden_nested_json>";
  final response = await http.get(url);
  var parsed = json.decode(response.body);

  AdsList ads = new AdsList.fromJson(Map.from(parsed));
  print(ads);
  return ads;
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79) article to clear more your serialization skills. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that's fine but, not the real problem, I updated the thread with json format and exception about the real problem. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, anyway to do this without changing json structure. trying to keep the [{},{},{}] structure. List of Maps structure, right?

Comment: Yes. You don't need change your json structure I just added the key named "adList" to make the explanation more clear and because in your example you display only a part of the json file and the key is missing.

Comment: in this case the json format does not have a key for the json array. so the json format is like this, [{...},{...}] not {"data" = [{...},{...},{...}]}. I probably should have formatted it the way your thinking like an object. but don't want to change the format just yet. So i guess I can't change var listOfMaps = List<Map<String,dynamic>>.from(json['adList']); to var listOfMaps = List<Map<String,dynamic>>.from(json['']);

Comment: I've changed the format in json now to be am object with key / array so getting closer. Will update later with next issue.

Comment: when I converted my json format to your json format everything works fine. thanks a lot. I came from python so not so used to working with json in dart yet :)

Comment: Okey. I am glad you could make it run!